# Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting') - problem trying to calculate R2

Tags: r, glmmtmb, glmm

I'm trying to fit a glmm using the package glmmTMB in R. The model has a Poisson distribution:

```
mod_po <- glmmTMB(richness ~ x_dif + x_dif2 + (1|papers/watersheds), data = df_glm, family = poisson).
```

The variables x_dif and x_dif2 are stream sizes, xdif is the linear variable and xdif2 the quadratic one. I centered these variables but the correlation is still high (0.85) and I can't take out the quadratic variable because of my hypothesis.
When I try to fit the model I receive this warning:
Warning message:

> In sqrt(diag(vcovs)) : NaNs produced

and the xdif2 has NaN in the summary. Is this because of the correlation between the variables? What can I do for fix it and keep the quadratic variable?

The summary:

```
> summary(mod_po)
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula:          
riqueza_larguras_unl ~ x_dif + x_dif2 + (1 | nomes_artigos_largura_unl/bacias)
Data: df_glm
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2927.8   2946.6  -1458.9   2917.8      314 
Random effects:
Conditional model:
 Groups                           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 bacias:nomes_artigos_largura_unl (Intercept) 0.09382  0.3063  
 nomes_artigos_largura_unl        (Intercept) 0.09382  0.3063  
Number of obs: 319, groups:  
bacias:nomes_artigos_largura_unl, 24; nomes_artigos_largura_unl, 24
Conditional model:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.087e+00  8.982e-02   34.37  < 2e-16 ***
x_dif       -7.929e-03  1.188e-03   -6.67 2.53e-11 ***
x_dif2       2.624e-05        NaN     NaN      NaN    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(vcovs)) : NaNs produced'
```

The diagnose:

```
predictors with unusually large or small standard deviations (|log10(sd)|>2120.57):
  x_dif2 
2120.565 
Predictor variables with very narrow or wide ranges generally
give rise to parameters with very large or small magnitudes,
which can sometimes exacerbate numerical instability, and may
also be appear (incorrectly) to be indicating a poorly defined
optimum (i.e., a non-positive definite Hessian
Unusually large Z-statistics (|x|>5):
(Intercept)       x_dif 
  34.368298   -6.671379 
Large Z-statistics (estimate/std err) suggest a *possible*
failure of the Wald approximation - often also associated with
parameters that are at or near the edge of their range (e.g.
random-effects standard deviations approaching 0).
(Alternately, they may simply represent very well-estimated
parameters; intercepts of non-centered models may fall in this
category.) While the Wald p-values and standard errors listed
in summary() may be unreliable, profile confidence intervals
(see ?confint.glmmTMB) and likelihood ratio test p-values
derived by comparing models (e.g. ?drop1) are probably still
OK.  (Note that the LRT is conservative when the null value is
on the boundary, e.g. a variance or zero-inflation value of 0
(Self and Liang 1987; Stram and Lee 1994; Goldman and Whelan
2000); in simple cases these p-values are approximately twice
as large as they should be.)
```

ALSO
When I try to get the r2 (with many packages) I receive a warning like this:
Warning messages:

```
1: In r.squaredGLMM.glmmTMB(mod_po) :
  the effects of zero-inflation and dispersion model are ignored
2: the null model is correct only if all variables used by the original model remain unchanged. 
3: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting').
```

Any suggestions?
My model didn't work and I need some help :)

Comment: using `poly(x_dif, 2)` rather than `x_dif + x_dif2` *might* help. Can you paste the results of `summary(mod_po)` into your answer? What are the results of `diagnose()`? It might be hard to help further without access to your data ...

Comment: PS it's not really worth trying to compute R^2 until you've cleared up the problems with the basic model ...

Comment: Hiii @BenBolker, thanks for the answer. I put the summary and diagnosis in the question now :)

Comment: What happens if you scale your variables as well as centering them??